Python Selenium - Unable to click on next page
I am trying to click on next page button with selenium but I am unable to. The next page does not load and the webpage shows an error, but in the URL box I can see that it clicked because the URL changes.
My code for trying to click on next page is like this:
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="page_charts_section_charts_item object_song"]'))
    )

next = True

while next == True:
    songs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="page_charts_section_charts_item object_song"]')
    for song in songs:
        song_artist = song.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="ui_name_locale_original"]')
        genre = song.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="genre comma_separated first"]')
        rating = song.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="page_charts_section_charts_item_details_average_num"]')
        song_list.append(song_artist[0].text)
        artist_list.append(song_artist[1].text)
        genre_list.append(genre.text)
        rating_list.append(rating.text)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="ui_pagination_next_label"]'))
        )
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="ui_pagination_next_label"]').click()
    except:
        next = False

And the webpage is this one:
https://rateyourmusic.com/charts/top/song/all-time/a:system%2dof%2da%2ddown/
On the normal browser I can click without any problem, but it seems that the selenium browser works different.
Any suggestion?
EDIT: The program clicks on the button because as you can see the URL changes, but the problem is that the new webpage does not load and throws an error (and this does not happen if you open a browser like a human and click on next button, so I don't know if it is some web scraping protection the site has).
Picture of the issue

Try to click the parent a tag of the <span class="ui_pagination_next_label"> instead of clicking the span itself.
